# Get Url in Angular1.5

Tags: angularjs

It's first time to use Angular1.5.
Here's my source code.

```
function config(stateHelperProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    stateHelperProvider
    .setNestedState({
      name        : 'main.browsejobs',
      url         : '/browse-jobs',
      params      : {keyword : ""},
      data        : { 
        pageTitle: 'Available jobs for Aditjobs',
        mastheadClass: 'browse-jobs'
      },
      children : {
        name: 'index',
        url: '/',
        templateUrl: '/par'
      },
      views       : {
        '': {
          templateUrl : 'components/browse-jobs/views/browse-jobs.view.html',
          controller  : "browseJobsController",
          controllerAs: 'vm',
          resolve: {
            jobFilters: jobFilters,
            jobPosts  : jobPosts,
            applyJob  : applyJob,
            jobPostsPagination: jobPostsPagination,
            locationFilters: locationFilters
          }
        },
        // 'testimonial@main.home': { 
        //   templateUrl : 'components/home/views/testimonial.view.html',
        // }
      }
    })
    $urlRouterProvider
    .otherwise('/404')
  }
```

I wanna get url like 'aditjobs/aaa' (for example) and I think I should use params in setNestedState function but this doesn't work.
How can I do this?

Comment: Hey, you welcome to stackoverflwo

Answer (score 0):

I mixed up with something.
      url         : '/browse-jobs/:jobid',
I can do it with that.